# What is the difference between singular and plural active record querying in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a book. I couldn't find proper explanation for this confusion that I am facing. I have model called **LineItem**

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Then there is a model called **Product** with a method

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items

    def method_name
        unless line_items.empty?
         do #this
        end
    end
end
```

There is a `line_items` in the above method.

Then there is a controller.

**app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb**

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
  ###---
  ##
end
```

What is up with the `line_items` here? I know singular model name gets generated as a plural table name. Is that like querying directly on table instead of Model.

Is `line_items.empty?` same as `LineItem.empty?`. Could somebody please explain this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is really very simple we have model name singular, table name plural but association can be singular or plural depends on how many records are associated. 
For eg.
User has many books. We can find many books like => User.last.books It will return all the books.
Book belongs to a user. We are defining a single user related with book. So Book.last.user

On other hand if you have single object associated with object. Then it will be has_one. Eg. 
User has_one :account. So to fetch related account we call. user.account not user.accounts.

In your case we have `product has_many :line_items` so when you have instance in create method `product = Product.find(params[:product_id])` and trigger product.line_items it will return multiple (if their are) line_items.

Have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand association in depth.

**Is line_items.empty? same as LineItem.empty?. Could somebody please explain this ?**

Answer is **NO**. Their is a huge difference between this 2.
object.line_items.empty? means is their any line_item present associated to object.
LineItem.empty? Is class method on LineItem can do what ever is in empty? if it is defined. Usually this is not present unless you define it explicitly.